# How to add ribbon command to exist ribbon tab

Tags: outlook, visual-studio-2015, ms-office, add-in, ribbon

I want to add command to Outlook 2016 Home Tab, and I follow the step: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx

But I cannot see the ribbon showing, and cannot find it from customize my ribbon

Is there any more detail walkthrough to follow to create a command to ribbon tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly do you expect to see your controls in Outlook? Is it an inspector or explorer window? May be appointment items? What context did you choose in the properties of the ribbon designer?

By default, if an add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.

Finally, make sure that the add-in is loaded by the host application. Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. See [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) for more information.